# How to print floating points with a number in dart

Tags: dart

I am new in dart programming.

```
main() {
  var a, b, c;
  a = 10;
  b = 5;
  c = a / b;
  print('$a / $b = $c');
}
```

This code will produce 2.0 as output. But if in the same code I want to print 2.00000000 (as much as I need 0 or other numbers in different cases.) then what should I do?

Like in C programming language we define our syntax:

```
printf(".5f", variable);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try [toStringAsFixed](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/num/toStringAsFixed.html).

```
main() {
  var a, b, c;
  a = 10;
  b = 5;
  c = a / b;
  print('$a / $b = ${c.toStringAsFixed(2)}');
}
```

Comment: how to do it inside the print statement like C ??

Comment: Use ${c.toStringAsFixed(2)}, instead of $c. I have updated my answer.